# What's wrong with BFS for finding shortest path lengths in weighted directed graph

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, shortest-path, dijkstra

Dijkstra's algorithm is the go-to method for finding the shortest path lengths between a source node and all the other nodes in a directed graph with nonnegative edge weights. I am wondering why the following plain BFS is not used more often?

```
distanceTo[sourceNode] = 0 # All the other entries are Inf.
frontier = [sourceNode]


# In Python, assume the graph is stored in a dictionary of dictionaries G. 
# G[x] retrives the neighors of node x, and G[x][y] gives weight of the edge
# from node x to node y.

while frontier:
  fnew = set() # New frontier.
  for x in frontier:
    neighbors = G[x]
    for y in neighbors:
      # Add y to the new frontier only if its distance to the
      # source node will change:
      if distanceTo[y] > distanceTo[x] + G[x][y]:
        distanceTo[y] = distanceTo[x] + G[x][y]
        fnew.add(y)
  frontier = fnew
```

Is the algorithm incorrect or does it have some flaws?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is performance. With Dijkstra's algorithm, it is guaranteed that when you take and remove a node from the frontier, its shortest path has been found, and that node will never be re-inserted into the frontier. So the total number of iterations of the outer loop is at most the number of nodes in the graph.

On the other hand, if you don't prioritise nodes by distance (such as in BFS, where nodes are prioritised by "number of edges" which is not the same as distance in a weighted graph), then each time you take and remove a node from the frontier, a shorter path to that node might yet be found via some other node in the frontier which you will consider later. That means each node may have to be processed many times.

Comment: Thanks you for the comment. Are you saying the worst-case time complexity of the above implementation is exponential? Could you link me to some reference?

Comment: @user2961927 I made a mistake, I was thinking about a worse version of the algorithm where the `distanceTo` table is updated when popping from the frontier, rather than when inserting into the frontier. I'm not sure what the worst case for your algorithm is, but it's definitely less efficient than Dijkstra's algorithm in the worst case.